# How to get number of printable characters from a env var

Tags: shell, zsh

In the terminal I can create env vars that have links in them. Example

```
foo='\e]8;;http://example.com\aThis is a link\e]8;;\a'
echo $foo                                                                                                   
This is a link
```

Then when ctrl+click on "This is a link" it opens a browser and navigates to http://example.com

However when I do the following:

```
echo $#foo                                                                                                  
48
```

So when counting using the # sign, it is counting all the chars, including the ones that don't print. What I want is a command that will output 14 and can handle variables that contain links or not.  Is such a thing possible?

Comment: You have to implement logic how to parse ANSI escape sequences. Actually, your example looks wrong to me. I would have expected something like `\e[8;;m` (i.e. _conceal_) instead of `\e]8;;`.

Comment: The escape commands are documented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), but I didn't find anything documented for an `\e]` sequence. What is your terminal type?

Comment: Side note (don't know whether this is imporant for you): While `foo` is not a variable, it is not an environment variable (unless it had been placed into the environment by the parent process already).